# How to create a custom manipulator that will format output into "pages"

Tags: c++

I need to format my output, so that when it goes through a specific number of `\n`, it will go to a "new page" by printing to console '----new page----'

[This is what i want to be displayed in my console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2HNg.png)

[image]

But I need to do it creating a custom manipulator that would handle such task

Here's what I have so far:

```
ostream &myc (ostream &s) {
    int i, j;
    for(i=0; s[i]!='\0'; i++){ //this doesn't work 
        if (s[i] == '\n') j+=1;
        if (j==2){  // each page will have only 2 lines 
            cout<<"\n---new page---\n";
            j = 0;
        }
    }
    cout<<s<<"\n";
    return s;
}
```

I know that `for` loop won't work, coz there's `no match of operator[]`, because
I have an `operator type s` and `int type i`. So my question is: how can I iterate through operator?

Comment: There is no way for a manipulator (or any other function) to count the number of newlines that have been written to a stream. You *can* check the currently buffered text, but no way of getting back text that has already been flushed. Instead of a manipulator I think a better design would be a custom `streambuf` implementation. Inherit from [`std::basics_streambuf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf), and implement the pager there.

Comment: Pipe your output through an existing pager like `more`.